# Bootstrapping a MST in R

Tags: r, bootstrap, graph-theory

I have a data matrix on GDP growth for particular countries for a particular period of time. From this matrix I get the correlation matrix. After that I use a nonlinear tranformation to obtain a distance matrix. From this matrix I construct a MST.

Now my task is to determine the stability of the links in the MST. For this purpose I need to utilize the bootstrap technique. I installed the `bootstrap` package and tried this (You also need the `ape` package for the `mst(X)` function):

```
theta <- function(X){corr_m <- cor(X, method = "pearson");dist_m <- sqrt(2*(1-corr_m))
mst(dist_m)};results <- bootstrap(bstrap_matrix,100,theta)
```

Where `bstrap_matrix` is my data matrix with columns corresponding to the countries (e.g. UK, Germany, France, ...) and rows corresponding to the periods of time (e.g. `2000Q1`, `2004Q3`, ...), but it does not work...

I want to obtain a matrix telling me how many times out of *R* resamplings the concrete edge of my MST was present even in the bootstrapped MST. This number is between one (occurred every time) and zero (never occurred).